# Find interception of rocket and skeet - TypeError

Tags: scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

For an assignment I need to calculate the angle beta for the launch of a rocket.
This rocket should hit a skeet in the air and the rocket is just accelerating in the first 0,5s.
In my first part of the exercise I already calculated the trajectory of the skeet. Next to the given parameters there is a wind in x-direction as well.
I am trying to calculate the angle beta by minimizing a wrapper function for the distance of both trajectories.
I always get the TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable sqrt method
I dont know what is my mistake and i hope someone can help me.
The experiment is looking like this:
[Picture - rocket - skeet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL7Lj.png)

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v_wind = 3.5 #m / s in positive x direction
rho_l = 1.2 # kg/m3

# skeet params
cw_skeet_top = 1.11
cw_skeet_side = 0.5
A_skeet_top = 0.0086
A_skeet_side = 0.00432
m_skeet = 0.105 #kg

v0_skeet = 40
x0_skeet = 60
y0_skeet = 0

# rocket params
cw_rocket_side = 1
cw_rocket_front = 0.5
A_rocket_side = 0.08
A_rocket_front = 0.0312
m_rocket = 2

v0_rocket = 0
x0_rocket = 20
y0_rocket = 0
F_accel_rocket = 120 #in Newton, divide by m_rocket to find accel in m/s^2
t_accel_end = 0.5

def drag(v_rel, rho_l, cw, A):
    Fw = rho_l * cw * A * v_rel**2/2.0
    if (v_rel < 0):
        Fw = -Fw
    return Fw

def skeet(t,y,rho_l,cw_skeet_side, cw_skeet_top,A_skeet_side,A_skeet_top,m_skeet):
    # Zur Übersichtlichkeit:
    # y[0] - x-position
    # y[1] - x-velocity
    # y[2] - y-position
    # y[3] - y-velocity

    d2xdt2 = -drag(y[1]-v_wind, rho_l, cw_skeet_side , A_skeet_side)/m_skeet   
    dxdt = -y[1]    
    d2ydt2 = -9.81 - drag(y[3], rho_l, cw_skeet_top, A_skeet_top)/m_skeet
    dydt = y[3]
    
    return dxdt, d2xdt2, dydt, d2ydt2

def hit_ground(t,y, *args):
    return y[2]
hit_ground.terminal = True
hit_ground.direction = -1

final_x = 0 #m
DGLargs=(rho_l,cw_skeet_side, cw_skeet_top,A_skeet_side,A_skeet_top,m_skeet)

def wrapperAlpha(alpha,final_x,DGLargs):
    tspan = [0, 100]
    maxStep=tspan[1]/1000  
    start_vec = [x0_skeet, v0_skeet*np.cos(alpha/180*np.pi), y0_skeet, v0_skeet*np.sin(alpha/180*np.pi)]
    sol = solve_ivp(skeet,tspan,start_vec,args=(DGLargs),max_step=maxStep,events=(hit_ground))
    return np.abs(sol.y[0,-1] - final_x)

starting_guess = 10 #deg
res = fsolve(wrapperAlpha, x0 = starting_guess, args = (final_x,DGLargs))

angle = res
print(angle)

tspan = [0, 100]
maxStep=tspan[1]/1000 

start_vec = [x0_skeet, v0_skeet*np.cos(angle/180*np.pi), y0_skeet, v0_skeet*np.sin(angle/180*np.pi)]
sol = solve_ivp(skeet,tspan,start_vec,args=(DGLargs),max_step=maxStep,events=(hit_ground))
x_skeet = sol.y[0,:]
y_skeet = sol.y[2,:]
plt.plot(x_skeet,y_skeet)

#important exercise:
RocketArgs = (rho_l,cw_rocket_side, cw_rocket_front,A_rocket_side,A_rocket_front,m_rocket,F_accel_rocket,t_accel_end)

def rocket(t,y,beta, rho_l,cw_rocket_side, cw_rocket_front,A_rocket_side,A_rocket_front,m_rocket,F_accel_rocket,t_accel_end):
    if t_accel_end > t:
        d2xdt2 = (-drag(y[1]-v_wind, rho_l, cw_rocket_side , A_rocket_side)+(F_accel_rocket*np.cos(beta/180*np.pi)))/m_rocket  
        dxdt = y[1]    
        d2ydt2 = (-9.81 - drag(y[3], rho_l, cw_rocket_front, A_rocket_front)+(F_accel_rocket*np.sin(beta/180*np.pi)))/m_rocket
        dydt = y[3]
    else:
        d2xdt2 = (-drag(y[1]-v_wind, rho_l, cw_rocket_side , A_rocket_side))/m_rocket  
        dxdt = y[1]    
        d2ydt2 = (-9.81 - drag(y[3], rho_l, cw_rocket_front, A_rocket_front))/m_rocket
        dydt = y[3]
        
    
    return dxdt, d2xdt2, dydt, d2ydt2

def wrapperRocket(beta,x_skeet,y_skeet,RocketArgs):
    tspan = [0, 100]
    maxStep = 0.01
    start_vec = [x0_rocket, v0_rocket*np.cos(beta/180*np.pi), y0_rocket, v0_rocket*np.sin(beta/180*np.pi)]
    sol2 = solve_ivp(rocket,tspan,start_vec,args=(beta,rho_l,cw_rocket_side, cw_rocket_front,A_rocket_side,A_rocket_front,m_rocket,F_accel_rocket,t_accel_end),max_step=maxStep,dense_output=True)
    for i in range(len(x_skeet)):
        distance = np.sqrt((sol2.y[0,i]-x_skeet)**2+(sol2.y[2,i]-y_skeet)**2)
    return distance 

starting_guess = 20 #deg
res = minimize(wrapperRocket, x0 = starting_guess, args = (x_skeet,y_skeet,RocketArgs))

angle = res
print(angle)
```

Comment: You asked several questions in the past and didn't upvote or accept most of the answers. Why should anyone be willed to delve into over 100 lines of code without any appreciation?

Comment: Im completely new to stackoverflow. I tried to upvote and mark my last questions now. Im just looking for help sorry